# How to return unique values in a list without reordering

Tags: java

In the following code, I have an arraylist that contains duplicated values:

```
List<Double> fitnesses = new ArrayList<Double>();
fitnesses.add(5.0);
fitnesses.add(1.0);
fitnesses.add(5.0);
fitnesses.add(2.0);
fitnesses.add(4.0);
fitnesses.add(2.0);
```

I want to remove the duplicates and for that I used the following:

```
Set<Double> hashsetList = new HashSet<Double>(fitnesses);
```

The problem is that the output that I get is:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

The issue is that I don't want the values to be sorted. Is there any way to remove the duplicates without reordering

Comment: LinkedHashSet will keep your order and dublicates will overwrite the old values.

Comment: which version of java are you using. if jaa 8 then use `list.stream().distinct()`

Comment: I'm more interested in why they are sorted in hashset. I mean set has no ordering, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking they arent "sorted" (not by their natural order) but are kept in this order in the HashMap because of the produced hashcodes of the Double class. If you add 1.123 to your list you will see that it will not appear between 1.0 and 2.0 because it's hashcode isn't between those 2.

Comment: @ShanuGupta because of the hash function. HashSet internally uses an array of buckets, and if the hash function that chooses the bucket is something like this: (int)Math.abs((int)x) then value 1, will be put into the first bucket, value 2 will be put into the second bucket, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use stream with distinct property.
`distinct()` is a function of stream which is added in java 8

**NOTE: If using java8**

`List<Double> distinctList = fitnesses.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

**NOTE: Before JAVA8**

```
Set<Double> uniqueRecords = new LinkedHashSet<Double>();
for (Double value : fitnesses){
    uniqueRecords.add(value);
}
System.out.println(uniqueRecords);
```

Or we van use:

```
Set<Double> uniqueRecords = new LinkedHashSet<Double>(fitnesses);
```

Output = [5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to/can't use the java 8 approach, you can insert your values into a `LinkedHashSet`, it preserves insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with java 8 stream and `distinct` command:

```
List<Double> collect = fitnesses.stream()
                                .distinct() //this is where the magic happens
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

> [5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]

Answer (score 1):

In J8 as the other answer this is the most effiscient :

```
List<Double> collect = fitnesses.stream()
                            .distinct() 
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also use a java.util.LinkedHashSet if you are not Java 8

```
Set<Double> hashsetList = new LinkedHashSet<Double>(fitnesses);
```

LinkedHashSet will preserve the order of added elements

Answer (score 1):

Using `LinkedHashSet` seems to work:

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    List<Double> fitnesses = new ArrayList<Double>();
    fitnesses.add(5.0);
    fitnesses.add(1.0);
    fitnesses.add(5.0);
    fitnesses.add(2.0);
    fitnesses.add(4.0);
    fitnesses.add(2.0);
    System.out.println("Original: "+fitnesses);
    // Get the unduplicated set.
    Set<Double> hashsetList = new LinkedHashSet<>(fitnesses);
    System.out.println("Deduplicated: "+hashsetList);
}
```

> Original: [5.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0]
>
> Unduplicated: [5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]